# How to close a window of a crashed application?

Tags: process, desktop-environment, awesome, window

Im using Awesome as desktop environment, as you can see in the image below, the application (aMule) crashed but the window is still open, so I would like to close it to restart it, but as you can see in terminal window it is not in list of process, so how can I close aMule window?

Even using <kbd>Mod4</kbd>-<kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>c</kbd> the window is not closed.

[image]

Comment: What does `xkill` say, if anything, after you try to use it to kill the window?

Comment: Oh hey, I'll post that as an answer, then.

Answer (score 6):

I would suggest using the utility `xkill` in this case.

If it didn't work, it would at least probably give some information explaining why.

Answer (score 3):

First of all, the fact that it is not shown in the first few lines of `top` does not mean that `aMule` is not running. In fact, since it has crashed, it is likely to be there in a zombie state, using next to no resources so not seeing it in `top` is normal. Instead of `top`, you should use `ps` or `pgrep` to find running processed:

```
pgrep amule
```

or

```
ps aux | grep amule
```

That should give you the process's PID which you can then use to kill it (change `1234` to the PID returned by `pgrep`):

```
kill -9 1234
```

Alternatively, you can try

```
killall -9 amule
```

Finally, the graphical program `xkill` will kill the process that spawned any window you click on.

Comment: +1. You can also use `xprop` to see what PID does the window belongs to.

Comment: Use `pgrep -l amule` instead. The -l switch will print the name of the process as well as the PID. That way, you know you're not mathcing against processes like `amulet` that contain `amule` as a substring.